# Store lab results using HealthKit API

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am currently reading through the Apple HealthKit API but didn't find a solution or reference to my problem.

I am currently developing an app to store custom health related values, like different blood test results from an lab. But I also want to support the Health App from Apple using the HealthKit, so the user can also track and share the values using the Health App.

The best I found was the LabRecord Type for the Clinical Documents but I was only able to find how to query those documents.

Here is my question: Is it possible to create a "clinical document" which is stored in the Health App and available there? For example to store values like the amount of red/white bloodcells, quantity of hormones, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot publish clinical documents to HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/samples/accessing_sample_data_in_the_simulator). The user must download health records from an [institution that is working with Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208647) to provide health records in [FHIR](http://hl7.org/fhir/) format.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you for the clarification. Is there any other way to store those lab results using the HealthKit? I mean, there is a great central point to store everything health related and I would love to use it. Also to provide a standardized way for the user to share those data.